# How do I deal with "stuck" headless chrome instances?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm running my Python script with 50 threads, therefore 50 chrome browsers will be open at any given time. The issue is, rarely, an unknown amount of browsers will get stuck - therefore limiting performance. And eventually, after a few hours, all browsers will end up being stuck. By stuck I assume, there has been an unforeseen error therefore the script is at a halt.

I've removed the headless flag and tried to diagnose said problems, but to no avail. Furthermore I've looked into killing threads/browsers which are open for longer than X amount of seconds but I can't seem to find anything simillar topics posted online. I've posted on Fiverr to seek paid help and all 7 people asked have no idea.

Ideally, if anybody knows how to check for browser alive time for each thread, and kill if it exceeds a set amount of seconds - would be greatly appreciated.

Tried:
Contacting people for paid work on Fiverr.
Researching thoroughly on all forum threads.
(I didn't try to write code myself, as I'm inexperienced).

Comment: The WebDriver gets stuck due to an error, so if you can catch the exception and quit the WebDriver, that won't keep unnecessary chrome instances running.

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you can post the code snippet and any errors that you're facing.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no visible errors, nothing outputs to CMD and it's running in headless. I suspect, as my script requires proxies and has to deal with cloudflare turnstiles, that maybe either the proxy dies, or the captcha expires. @Zero

Comment: Exception handling will take care of that because it returns an error if a proxy isn't working or the WebDriver times out. You might be having something already to turn off the logging, as you're running 50 instances already.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.